# using raw-data from an infinite input and playing it on the device

Tags: java, android, arrays

I would like to know how to capture data(media) from an infinite input stream(eg. internet radio) and play it on the android device.Most of the tutorials i have gone through, tell me to use the MediaPlayer class. But the problem is that i want to capture that raw data in a byte array and then play it from that byte array itself.Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the AudioRecord class? with it you can record audio from sources, i.e. a MIC and read into a byte[], the class for reading out of a byte[] would be AudioTrack. please find the links within this post.

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html

hope it will help.

as you said, you want to capture from internet radio, i am not sure how to do that. sorry